# How to change return type of a Map() object

Tags: javascript, dictionary, types

I faced a type error when I store an item in a `JavaScript Map`. Is there a way to fix the return type of a value in a map? The below code implies, the returned type is an `object` but not `WebGLTexture`.

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'bindTexture' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': parameter 2 is not of type 'WebGLTexture'.
```

**The Code Snippet**

```
const textures = new Map();
// ...  
console.log('Texture:',newTexture) 
textures.set(uuid ,newTexture);

let createdObject = textures.get(uuid);
console.log('WebGL Object:',createdObject)
console.log('Type:', typeof createdObject)
```

**Related Console Log**

[image]

Comment: const textures = new Map() as WebGLTexture ;

Comment: the code is not written in ts. When I tried this, it said: `Type assertion expressions can only be used in TypeScript files.`

Comment: @MohitSharma  That's Typescript, and even if the OP was using Typescript it wouldn't fix the error..

Comment: Map is not going to change the type of an object, there is something else here missing.  btw.  `typeof` only shows `object` no matter what the class is.

Comment: You are right. I checked what was the type before map as `console.log('Type before:', typeof newTexture)` it printed `object`. How can I see the real types ?

Comment: `newTexture.constructor.name`  Please be aware className's in JS are not globally unique, IOW:  It's possible for two classes called `XYZ`, so it's really only meant for debug purposes..  Of course in your case it's unlikely you would have 2 classes called `WebGLTexture`, but just thought it worth a mention.

Comment: When I checked the `constructor.name` in multiple parts of the project. The name is correct as `WebGLTexture` at the file that I asked as question but it is wrong as `Map` when it is used in a different file. I have actually created this variable in a `react context` as `const defaultVal = new Map();`
`const context = createContext({  textures: defaultVal })` maybe that causes the problem

Comment: Are you doing `context.textures`, the context shouldn't be altering the object either, are you able to knock up an example snippet with the problem.?

Comment: Well, I could not figure out when or how the type changes. I solved the problem by initializing the Map with a random key, and empty texture pair. Your comments helped a lot. Thank you!